# Wagtail Inline Panel - Sort Order

Tags: django, wagtail

So I'm struggling with ordering the choices within an InlinePanel (for an orderable) on my site. In the admin page, when adding a new item, the options are presented in the order they were added to the site (so, essentially the 'id' for that item); this is less than ideal considering there are hundreds of options presented in a manner that is not user friendly.

I'm assuming this needs to be defined as ordering meta within the orderable, but I can't seem to get it to work. This is what my orderable looks like:

```
class RelatedPeople(Orderable):
    service = ParentalKey('service.Services', related_name='related_person')
    person = models.ForeignKey('person.People', null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='related_service')

panels = [
    FieldPanel('person')
]
```

I've tried the following with no success:

```
class Meta:
    ordering = 'person'
```

and, trying to append the field within 'person' that I want to sort by, 'name':

```
class Meta:
    ordering = 'person.name'
```

There must be an obvious way to solve this that I'm over looking. A default sort order of the 'id' (in this case, for 'person.People') is rarely ever going to be suitable from the perspective of the content creator.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance,

Rob

Answer (score 2):

Person model should have:

```
    ordering = ['name']
```

instead of

```
    ordering = 'name'
```

And your Orderable object should have it's meta changed to

```
    class Meta(Orderable.Meta):
```

Via Django Docs, this is the example of abstract base classes, and ordering:

> Meta and multi-table inheritance¶
>
> In the multi-table inheritance situation, it doesn’t make sense for a
>   child class to inherit from its parent’s Meta class. All the Meta
>   options have already been applied to the parent class and applying
>   them again would normally only lead to contradictory behavior (this is
>   in contrast with the abstract base class case, where the base class
>   doesn’t exist in its own right).
>
> So a child model does not have access to its parent’s Meta class.
>   However, there are a few limited cases where the child inherits
>   behavior from the parent: if the child does not specify an ordering
>   attribute or a get_latest_by attribute, it will inherit these from its
>   parent.
>
> If the parent has an ordering and you don’t want the child to have any
>   natural ordering, you can explicitly disable it:
>
> ```
>    class ChildModel(ParentModel):
>     # ...
>     class Meta:
>         # Remove parent's ordering effect
>         ordering = []
> ```
>
> When an abstract base class is created, Django makes any Meta inner
>   class you declared in the base class available as an attribute. If a
>   child class does not declare its own Meta class, it will inherit the
>   parent’s Meta. If the child wants to extend the parent’s Meta class,
>   it can subclass it. For example:
>       from django.db import models
>
> ```
> class CommonInfo(models.Model):
>     # ...
>     class Meta:
>         abstract = True
>         ordering = ['name']
>
> class Student(CommonInfo):
>     # ...
>     class Meta(CommonInfo.Meta):
>         db_table = 'student_info'
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with `Wagtail`, but can you take a look at this issue :

https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/issues/4477#issuecomment-382277375

**Update**:

Maybe you just need to update your `Person` model like this:

```py
class Person(models.Model):
    ...

    class Meta:
        ordering = 'name'
```

In your files, you try to order `RelatedPeople` by `Person`, but what you need is to order the `Person` list by `name` in your wagtail dropdown

Comment: Hey, thanks for looking. That relates to changing the order of already selected objects - which I have working. Unfortunately, this isn't what I'm struggling with; I'm trying to order the drop-down list to make the process of selecting an object in the first place user-friendly - I need to make that alphabetical so we're not scrolling through 400+ names (always growing) to find the right one (it's currently sorted by id, not by the persons name). I appreciate you having looked though.

Comment: Can you tell me in which file did you add the `class Meta / ordering`? Because after rereading your post, I think you just need to put the `ordering` in the `Person` model and not in the `RelatedPeople Orderable`

Comment: Person already has that class Meta in place in that models.py. I'm actually thinking the issue may be more to do with how the built-in InlinePanel function is working with the (built-in) Orderable class type. I now think adding ordering to the Orderable would actually break the function that allows a user to manually define ordering for that grouping.